# BSOD Dell Latitude 3540

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I need help with a BSOD case on two Dell Latitude 3540 notebooks: First, these notebooks showed the blue screen with the message

> FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE

so in research I found that the error can be caused by Fast Boot in Windows 10, I deactivated the Fast Boot feature and the machines worked without error for a few days.

Recently, the machines returned the BSOD error, but the message was changed to

> SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED

After this last error, I ran some tests, such as sfc, chkdisk, hardware test using Dell software and no error was detected.

So can you help me how I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: All I can suggest it to see if there are any new drivers on the Dell support page for your model, and install them. Only real way to see what is causing it is to debug the Windows crash dump file, which cannot be explained here due to the complexity.

Comment: Looks like the only Windows 10 2018 driver is for Intels ime, iI would install it......http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-3540-laptop/drivers

Comment: About the drivers, I've done this, but I'll check again. And about the crash dump, I verified and found something about "MemCompression" and "win32kbase.sys", but on research I don't found nothing that help me.

Comment: [analyze the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)